# Flexbox confusion

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was practicing the flexbox and got stuck at a specific practice. Firstly i have a navbar from bootstrap and a cdn from bootstrap. Under the navbar is completely empty and its the place where i am trying to put 4 different columns divided evenly across the window and under the navbar. That's something can't do cause of some reason. I tried all the flexbox commands but nothing. Could anyone explain me the reason why my css won't work? https://jsfiddle.net/3k2xvt1k/#&togetherjs=FARNdVGlUO

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


    <title>Hover</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hover.css">



</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <span class="brand">YORGOS LAFAZANIDIS</span>
  <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#">Culture</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#">Bundles</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<section class="b">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
  <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
</section>

<section class="b2">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
  <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
</section>

<!-- <section class="b3">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
  <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
</section>

<section class="b4">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
  <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
</section>
 -->




</body>

</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.brand {
    color: #706965;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav-item {
    margin: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: #706965;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.b {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #ccc1c1;
    max-width: 25%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}

.b2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #ccc1c1;
    max-width: 25%;
    min-height: 100vh;


}

.b3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #ccc1c1;
    max-width: 25%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.b4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #ccc1c1;
    max-width: 25%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that CSS does not work. It's that it doesn't work as you expect it. There is no way for us to know what your expectations are from the code above, unless you specify them in clear: "*I expect `a` to do **b** as per linked official documentation **c**"*. Please specify what it is you expect from what value of what attribute and we can point you to the documentation stating why it doesn't happen and, most likely, we might give you an alternative into obtaining the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this wat u want ?

link to fiddle [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gautamnaik1994/3k2xvt1k/1/)

So basically i wrapped your 4 sections in row and gave them each a `col` class.

This will equally distribute the space among the 4 columns

```
<div class="row m-0">
  <section class="col b">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
    <p>
      <h5>Text text text</h5>
    </p>
  </section>

  <section class="col b2">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
    <p>
      <h5>Text text text</h5>
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="col b3">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
    <p>
      <h5>Text text text</h5>
    </p>
  </section>

  <section class="col b4">
    <h1>Hero text</h1>
    <p>
      <h5>Text text text</h5>
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what i want! "row" is a bootstrap class? and m-0?

Comment: @GiwrgosLaphazanidhs , both are bootstrap classes, row for aligning children in row and m-0 for margin 0

Answer (score 0):

`flex` is a property that you have to give to a `parent element`, to the child append `flex-grow:1;`. so the solution will be wrap the columns in a `display:flex` `div` and give to each column `flex-grow:1;` like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>


        <title>Hover</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hover.css">
        <style>
            .brand {
                color: #706965;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 21px;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }

            .nav-item {
                margin: 15px;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a {
                color: #706965;
            }

            a:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .col-container{
                display: flex;
            }
            .col{
                flex-grow: 1;
                background-color: #ccc1c1;
            }
        </style>


    </head>

    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <span class="brand">YORGOS LAFAZANIDIS</span>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Culture</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Bundles</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-container">
        <section class="col">
            <h1>Hero text</h1>
            <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
        </section>

        <section class="col">
            <h1>Hero text</h1>
            <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
        </section>

        <section class="col">
            <h1>Hero text</h1>
            <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
        </section>

        <section class="col">
            <h1>Hero text</h1>
            <p><h5>Text text text</h5></p>
        </section>
    </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

hope it is what you want..

Comment: Thank you a lot for helping out both of you! Both got it right. So whatever i am doing with flexbox i need to wrap it up with a div and a name that not mix with bootstrap cdn and inside the class only needs to have display: flex inside ? And then im going to give a class to each section with whatever name and put flex-grow 1 so they equally take all the width of the window? shouldnt we put a flex-direction :column as well so that they will be vertically?

Comment: please see the example in the answer. i add the styles in the `<head/>`. generally - yes, the wrapper only have to be `display:flex` and the column only need `flex-grow:1`. and about vertically.. what you mean? the "hero text" is anyway above the "text text text' because the default of div is to be 100% width so the next div will appear below